# Is it possible to use certain libraries only in debug mode in android?

Tags: android, retrofit, interceptor

Hi I want to use certain library and their code in debug mode only. Is it possible?
For example. I use retrofit logging for debug mode only.
How can I use this logging library only in debug build.

I can use debugImplementation to use for debug build only but the code compilation fails in production because Logging code of app still exists.

Answer (score 1):

You use `debugImplementation` to only include the real library in debug mode.

In addition, in the `src/release` branch, you add no-op implementations for the API that your code calls directly. Call it a shim or a façade or a stub. If these classes end up being quite large, it may be a sign that your debug-only library is not cleanly separated from your production code.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create a debug version of your files by creating a corresponding folder with a file of the same name.

So under root/app/src you usually have the main and/or release folder. If you create a folder such as root/app/src/debug and copy your file into this folder you can modify this file for debug specific purposes.

If I recall correctly, Android usually have 3 folder: main, debug and release. 'main' works as a default folder. If your files are not defined in the release and debug folder, it will use the main file.

Do be aware of that if you change any general functionality, you need to copy that to the other versions of the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this..
Leak Canary library works only in debug mode.

in build.gradle implement your library like this.

```
dependencies {
    // debugImplementation because LeakCanary should only run in debug builds.
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.7'
}
```

Comment: I understood this. But If I have to use leakcanary code on activity, it would not compile when built in release mode unless we comment out that coce.